# Начал пробовать работать с базами данных (отписка подписка на рассылку через телеграмм) на Python. При запуске кода появляется ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пробовал переустанавливать версию пайтон (3.8.3). Пробовал переустановить библиотеку(Aiogram). Ошибка не в коде, она появляется после запуска кода.

Код ошибки

```
Exception ignored in: <function BaseBot.__del__ at 0x000001A847DF7B80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python2\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 109, in __del__
  File "D:\Python2\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 758, in new_event_loop
  File "D:\Python2\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 656, in new_event_loop
  File "D:\Python2\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 310, in __init__
  File "D:\Python2\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 632, in __init__
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001A847F0DA30>
```

Код

```
    import config
    import logging

    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
    from sqlighter import SQLighter


    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
    #подключение к базе данных
    db = SQLighter('db.db')

    #Подписка
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
    async def echo(message: types.Message):
        if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
            db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)
        else:
            db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, True)

        await message.answer("Вы успешно подписались на рассылку!\nЖдите новостей от сообщества.")

    #Отписка
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
    async def  unsubscribe(message: types.Message):
        if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
            # если пользователя не было в базе, добавляем его с неактивной подпиской 
            db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id, False)
            await message.answer("Вы итак не подписаны.")
        else:
            db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, False)
            await message.answer("Вы отписались от рассылки.")



if __name__ == '_main_':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: То есть если код запускается, в нем ошибки нет?)

Answer (score 1):

[Отсюда](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/issues/305#issuecomment-615066838).

> Проблема в том, что клиент `aiohttp` должен быть закрыт, либо вручную
>   `await bot.close()`, либо автоматически при использовании `executor`.

Вы используете последние версии связанных библиотек, в частности `aiohttp`?

Если нет обновитесь, если да, понизьте версию `aiohttp`.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Где должна находиться строчка await bot.close() ? А как проверить закрывается ли клиент при использовании executor ?

Comment: я бы для начала проверил версии связанных библиотек и обновил\понизил для проверки